# Sumar Columna de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo un `DataGridView` con datos, y un método `OnRowDataBound` que me sumara los datos de la columna `Precio`, alojando el total de los precios en un `TextBox` "totaltxt";

El método funciona bien, suma los datos y los muestra en el `TextBox` el problema es, que al sumar los valores de la columna precio no me suma el ultimo valor quedando con un total no exacto... adjunto método y grilla:

[image: Metodo onrowdatabound]

[image: grilla]

Como se ve en la grilla el valor total debería ser `27.000` y no `22.000`

PD:
He probado cambiando el `PageSize` y activando el `ShowFooter` para que contara la ultima `row` pero nada ha servido.

Comment: Como observación es mejor que coloques el código como tal y no una imagen del código...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar la suma fuera de ese evento en algún otro lugar de tu código algo como esto:

```
int total = GrillaClientes.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Sum(x => (int?)x.Cells[3].Value ?? 0);
totalTxt.Text = total.ToString();
```

> Se realiza la suma tomando en cuenta que si la celda es nula, el valor para esa celda será un cero `0`, para evitar excepciones. Además en vez de usar `Cast` se puede usar `OfType<DataGridViewRow>()` para evitar otra posible excepción al tratar de convertir a `DataGridViewRow`.

*Editada* agregando validación para filas vacías, estoy desde el móvil, no he probado el código, por si cualquier error.

O seguir usando el evento `RowDataBound` de esta manera:

```
int total = 0; 
protected void GrillaClientes_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[3].Text))
            total += Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
    }
    totalTxt.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Esto debería funcionar correctamente.

> *Nota:* Otras posibles excepciones debes controlarlas tú...

Comment: y si hay una celda vacia(null)en la columna que pasara? no seria mejor validar antes de sumar

Comment: @Manny el debe controlar las excepciones que se le pueden presentar, simplemente es una linea de código para validar que no esté vacía. Pero es válida tu aclaración, editaré la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

en wpf 2022

```
public void sumar()
     {
     decimal total = datagrid1.ItemsSource.OfType<DataRowView>()
     .Sum(x => (decimal?)Convert.ToDecimal(x["columnaname"]) ?? 0);
      texttoresultado.text = total.ToString("N2");

    }
```

Comment: No olvides explicar el funcionamiento del código. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._ Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.